# Which is efficient: a recursive function or a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, recursion, iteration

I was making a program for calculating factorials. We can use either a recursive function or a for loop. I want to know which one is efficient and why?

**recursive:**

```
int fact(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return n*fact(n-1);
}
```

**iterative:**

```
int fact(int n)
{
    int a=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        a=a*i;
    }
    return a;   
}
```

Comment: Since you presented neither, we can't really answer that can we? Or are you asking for a tutorial on performance benchmarking?

Comment: Without code, a specific example, attempts how you solve it or your results in profiling both versions theres only one valid answer: Profile it.

Comment: @Anedar I've entered the code . Please have a look again

Comment: @kfsone I've entered the code . Please have a look again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the general principle, using a for-loop will get rid of the overhead of function call and parameter passing.

Nevertheless, modern optimizing compilers may in some conditions optimize your recursive code away.  In [this online demo](https://goo.gl/pW0qUU) showing the assembler code, you see that with `-O2` in gcc the assembly code generated to the recursive and the iterative version are exactly the same:

```
fact(int):                 ; explanation added by me
    testl   %edi, %edi     ; test value of parameter
    movl    $1, %eax       ; take 1 as a return value
    je      .L4            ; if parameter was 0, jump to the return statement
.L3:
    imull   %edi, %eax      ; multiply future return value in register eax by the parameter n in edi register
    subl    $1, %edi        ; substract 1 to n in the edi register
    jne     .L3             ; this loops unitl it's 0 
    rep ret                 ; return 
.L4:
    rep ret
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of recursion is called tail recursion, which basically means that the recursive call is the last statement in the function. It is converted to a loop by any modern compiler.

Aside from that, as long as you are using integers, you can only calculate a small number of factorials anyways. So if you really want performance, use a lookup table.